# CSS loading but not working on first load - ie7,ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have this head

```
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo FO_CSS_PATH . 'all.css'; ?>" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo FO_JS_PATH . 'jquery-1.8.0.min.js'; ?>"></script>
</head>
```

`FO_CSS_PATH` and `FO_JS_PATH` is correct and fully working on all other browsers.

First of all when I click on a link and open new page, the css is fully loaded (I can see it in developer tools from ie). I don`t think I have any error in my css because if I press <kbd>F5</kbd> (refresh), the page is fully loaded.

So, when I open a page, the css is loading but not working. If I press <kbd>F5</kbd> it is fully working.

PS. I found the same problem on this website: http://forums.asp.net/t/1180199.aspx/1/10, but i'm not working with ASP and there I didn't find a good solution.

Comment: Make sure you have cleared browser cache before testing!!

Comment: Did you try to clear the browser cache by any chance?

Comment: @ssilas777 i have cleared and tested on many other computers in ie7 and 8 it is not working!

Comment: Can you try <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo FO_CSS_PATH . 'all.css?_23512531312'; ?>" />

Comment: @bhatanant2 i solved the problem .. the css file was loaded dinamically , for every page i was using all.css but it wasn`t the same css and browser was loading the previous page css.. so i used a param for every page like "all.css?home", "like.css?my_account" and now all works great..

Answer (score 0):

First, try with the actual path of the CSS file (no PHP at all) to see if the problem persists. If so, double-check if the problem occurs on another PC with the same version of IE. If the problem is still there, you will have to try another new CSS file that you just created with some random properties just to test.

If it still not work only on some specific versions of IE, I would check for the charset used to create your file (with a great text editor like notepad++). Be sure that the charset used to save the file is the same as the one declared in your php header() or html meta.

It really looks like IE isn't detecting properly the charset of your CSS file or your PHP/html page. When it refreshes, it now detects properly.